# Custom iOS Loading Icons

Tags: ios, gif

I would like to create a custom iOS loading icon from an app that I am considering using a .gif would this be possible, give the frame rate or would this look bad?

If, I should not use a gif, what is generally the best approach, I have seen many custom loading icons in apps (yelp, google) are these usually gifs?, just no one really discussing making them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` [supports animation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624094-animatedimagenamed), but I'm not sure if it could load animated GIFs. Instead it loads images in common formats (JPG, PNG, etc.) from multiple files. If you really need animated GIFs, you can load them with ImageIO framework.